# WebView не загружает видео

Tags: java, android, webview, videoview

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой. WebView не загружает видео. То есть верстка встаёт правильно и видеозаписи в нужном месте. Но по нажатию на видео ни чего не происходит.
Делал по гайдам.

В манифесте:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.BlogsItem"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

В лайауте там пару вьюшек, кнопок и примерно в цетре WebView, скрипт приходит с сервера, пример скрипта я выложил:

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

В активити:

```
    String script = "видосвидосвидосвидосвидосвидос\n" +
            "<br />видос\n" +
            "<br />\n" +
            "<br />\n" +
            "<br /><video width=\"350.0\" controls=\"controls\"><source      src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgmtS4n4ujY\" type=\"video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2\"></video>\n" +
            "<br />\n" +
            "<br />\n" +
            "<br />два видоса\n" +
            "<br />\n" +
            "<br /><video width=\"350.0\" controls=\"controls\"><source src=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-4msD7eo0g\" type=\"video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2\"></video> <st yle>img{max-width:350.0px;!important} body{margin: 0; padding: 0}</style>";

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, script, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

вот ссылка на блог http://justme.webformula.pro/personal/blog/first-blog/38/

в loadDataWithBaseURL() вместо null я побывал вставить ссылку, толку нет.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой помогите пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String html = "<html><body>123<br> <iframe width=\"320\" height=\"315\"" +
            " src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/X-4msD7eo0g\" frameborder=\"0\" " +
            "allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Важный момент, видео должно быть  embed, тоесть  ссылка https://www.youtube.com/embed/X-4msD7eo0g

Если webview не принципиально, есть вот такой вариант для ютуба https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/?hl=ru#How_It_Works

Comment: Спасибо!!! сделали видео embed и теперь всё норм.

Answer (score 1):

WebView - это базовый движок без плагинов.
Для проигрывания видео Вам нужен соответствующий плагин, интегрированный Вами в Ваше приложение.

В контектсе Андройда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708890/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview-android

UPD: about onShowCustomView() : This method was deprecated in API level 18. This method supports the obsolete plugin mechanism, and will not be invoked in future

решение, вероятно, перестанет работать в будущем.

Тут тоже есть примеры кода: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109083/android-webview-video-play

UPD2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223433/jwplayer6-giving-error-2035-on-firefox-for-youtube-videos - видимо, нужно поставить проигрывание не средствами flash а средствами **html5**.

UPD3: https://shashikaonline.com/2013/06/25/play-html5-video-on-android-webview/

This is the test HTML page which has a video element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Save this file in the assets folder. In the Android activity load the url into the WebView.

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

You should get the Internet permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: я находил эти примеры, ничего не помогло :(( может есть какие то библиотеки?

Comment: Возможно, это поможет: https://shashikaonline.com/2013/06/25/play-html5-video-on-android-webview/